# How to structure many and/or complex SQL queries?

Tags: sql

Having quite a lot of SQL queries, many of them ad-hoc-ones, a database has grown a bit messy.  I have two problems :

1. Hard to keep many different views/sproc's in good order when only using names to structure them
2. Subqueries (views that calls other views, in 2-4 levels) adds to the structure mess and are hard to maintain

Now I like to get a better structure in my database and/or in my C# code (could be java/python/ruby/whatever). How?

Should I use "schemas" in SQL to separate views in different areas? Like namespaces.

Should I avoid having lot of TSQL in the database altoghether and instead keep the querying to my C#? That would move the database logic closer to the rest of the system, and would be much easier to maintain and keep in code versioning, but at the same time I appreciate being close to the data, to keep performance good (with the help of SQL profiler).

Any other suggestion?

Update: the database and the c#-projects are a few years old and has grown, and will continue to grow over time (different areas of functionality) + new projects will be added. I need to clean it up in a good way, or change strategy.

Comment: should you consider scalability?

Comment: To be able to add more servers? Not primarily, but I need to know if something I do makes that more complicated.

Comment: Are you talking about MS SQL Server? I'm not sure you can get definitive answer to a question as open as this one.

Comment: yes, but I do think the problems could be the same in any sql db?

Comment: What do you mean by keep queries in the code? Do you use LINQ or you use ADO .NET?

Comment: Queries in application code, meaning having (or generating) the actual TSQL in the application and not in the database. Using for example plain TSQL strings or LinqToSql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ok, why is complexity in your C# code easier to manage than complexity in your TSQL?**

It must be that either your tooling for or knowledge of C# is superior. You should address that.

You can adopt naming conventions, and organise files to aid in this task. Use development environments to support TSQL and source control. Make sure you can deploy new and upgraded database schemas programmatically. Just like you should with C#.

Without knowing the details of your project I can't specify an exact structure.

**How should you decide where logic should be implemented?**

At a generic level this is simple.

The database should perform set based operations that can benefit from the use of indecies on your data. This code is easier to write in TSQL and other set based query languages.

Your application/business layer should perform row level operations, ideally in a stateless (`Shared`/`static`) fashion. This code is easier to write in c#, and other procedural languages.

Scaling database servers is more difficult than a stateless application layer. How do you maintain synchronization across multiple machines?

---

There is no exact right answer. There are just many shades of grey. The best solution will be based on your requirements. Start with the MS Defacto VS 2013, SQL 2012, C#, EF6 and embellish or simplify from there.

Comment: Thanks, yea, I added a bit of info about the project(s). It's not the exact structure - more a good, proven by experience, strategy I need. I never worked with schemas, and feel that tooling (SSMS) are not very good there. And I think the (non-schema) structure I have is just an example of bad software practice and a headache to maintain.

Comment: I take it you prefer to keep the TSQL inside the DB, in views and sprocs - and only add a thin "one-function-per-view/sproc" layer in C#?

Comment: I have a long time experience with SQL but probably need to deepen it - or need better tools. I will have a look at Redgate ones now.

Comment: Ok, using schemas now, structure is much nicer. SSMS limited UI help for schemas had me fooled, but writing a few sql commands is not that much work.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this article by Martin Fowler "Domain Logic and SQL" http://martinfowler.com/articles/dblogic.html .

Performance first?

"One of the first questions people consider with this kind of thing is performance. Personally I don't think performance should be the first question. My philosophy is that most of the time you should focus on writing maintainable code. Then use a profiler to identify hot spots and then replace only those hot spots with faster but less clear code"

Maintainability

"For any long-lived enterprise application, you can be sure of one thing - it's going to change a lot. As a result you have to ensure that the system is organized in such a way that's easy to change. Modifiability is probably the main reason why people put business logic in memory [= application code instead of TSQL]."

Encapsulation

"Using views, or indeed stored procedures, provides encapsulation only up to a point. In many enterprise applications data comes from multiple sources, not just multiple relational databases, but also legacy systems, other applications, and files. [...] In this case full encapsulation really can only be done by a layer within the application code, which further implies that domain logic should also sit in memory."